# Start the script with sudo not working

Tags: shell-script, virtualbox, daemon

I am trying to start the virtual machine (ORACLE VIRTUALBOX) using this script (script name: `start_vm001.sh`).

```sh
START_VM=`/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless --startvm testvm001`
EXECUTE_VM=`exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --chuid 1001 \
--exec "$START_VM" -- $START_VM`
echo $EXECUTE_VM
```

```bash
$ ./start_vm001.sh, # it worked
$ sudo ./start_vm001.sh # it not worked

ERROR OUTPUT: sbin/start-stop-daemon: unable to stat Oracle VM VirtualBox 
Headless Interface 4.1.12_Ubuntu (C) 2008-2013 Oracle Corporation All rights 
reserved. Invalid machine name or UUID! (No such file or directory)
```

How to run the script using sudo?

Comment: One of the advantage of vbox is that it don't needs to be root to start the vm. Do you really needs sudo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by calling this script using another script:

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid 1001 --exec /etc/init.d/start_vm001.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first line you are executing the VBoxHeadless command instead of just putting the line in a variable. You should be using the following syntax:

```
START_VM="/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless --startvm testvm001"
```